# Non primality of a pseudo-like Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $35\times2^m+1$ is $\textbf{not}$ a prime number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $m$ is even the number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: In general, it is easy to see that for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0,\pm1$, there is an infinite arithmetic progression of $m$’s such that $ab^m+c$ is composite.

Comment: Any reason for $35$ in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For natural $k$ let $m=4+10k$.
Then $35 \times 2^m+1$ is divisible by $11$, since
$35 \cdot 2^{4+10k} \equiv -1 \pmod {11}$
and $2^m$ is periodic modulo all primes.

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $m$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $35 \times 2^n+1$ is divisible by $35 \times 2^m+1$.  Indeed, it suffices to take $n$ such that
$2^{n-m} \equiv 1 \mod 35 \times 2^m+1$.